# 3D Separating Axis Theorem, what axis to test?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector, collision-detection

I know I need to project the vertices of my polyhedra on a whole bunch of axes, i've read these axes are the normals to each of the faces of one polyhedra (or is it both?). I've also read i use the cross product of each edge of one collidable with each edge of the other collidable. So lets say i have 2 polyhedra each with 8 faces and 12 edges. Therefore there would be 8 + (12*12) = 152 axes to project and then subsequently test? Is that correct?

Also since i dont know whether my faces are CW or CCW, my normals could be pointing inside or outside, does this matter? For example lets say i project onto an axis that is a normal from one of the shapes facing inwards, as long as both polyhedra are projected using this same normal, will this effect the algorithm?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Try http://www.mathoverflow.net

Comment: @Jon: You should read the FAQ in the sites you link to, at the least. That site is for research-level questions only. This is not such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the only planes you need to check are those that are defined by the faces of your objects; that is, the normal of the faces is the normal of the planes to check. The direction of the normal doesn't matter, since you're just projecting the vertices anyway.

Also note that this only works for convex meshes, and isn't necessarily the quickest way to do these kinds of checks. You might want to look into XenoCollide or GJK instead; those are becoming standard.

Comment: i dont need to test the cross product of the edges? Yeah i got as far as getting my GJK algorithm working 99.99% of the time, but i've shelved it due a) that 0.01% that is gets stuck in an infinite loop and b) getting the penetration depth is an even harder and less robust algorithm. I took a look at MPR but it seems to suffer from the same rubustness and depth issues. I figure ill get an SAT algorithm for polyhedra with a low number of vertices working before i give my gjk another go...

Comment: @user: The normal of the faces *is* the cross product of the edges.

Comment: @GManNickG No. He is talking about the cross product of pairs of edges. One from partA the other from partB. If you are talking cubes then you don't need to do this as the edges are all parallel to the face normals so you end up with duplicate axes when you do the cross products. But generally you need to use the cross products.

Answer (score 4):

The theorem says that you project the polyhedrons to a 2D plane and if you find an axis on which they don't overlap they don't collide. The problem is to find the right plane/axis in the least amount of attempts. So you use the polyhedron face's normals as separating axes for test as well as their cross product for test if they collide on the edges.

In your example if you have 2 polyhedrons each with 8 faces and 12 edges, you first test the 8 normals of each polyhedron as the separating axes. If each of them a separating axes you can assume that the polyhedrons don't collide. Then you can check the cross products of the normals as separating axes to eliminate the edge-on-edge non-colliding cases.

I hope this helped.